How to animate VisionOS WindowGroup size?
How to animate the size of a WindowGroup when it is presented?
Assuming we have this app:
struct Vision_proApp: App {

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            FirstView()
        }
        
        WindowGroup(id: "secondWindowGroupId") {
            SecondView()
        }
        .defaultWindowPlacement { content, context in
            return WindowPlacement()
        }
        .windowResizability(.automatic)

    }
}

With:
struct FirstView: View {
    @Environment(\.openWindow) private var openWindow
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("open second window group") {
            openWindow(id: "secondWindowGroupId")
            
        }
    }
}

How can I animate the FirstView button action? I want my secondWindowGroup to have an animation when it’s presented, where its size changes—like, for example, doubling in size. Imagine you have a video that’s presented and you want it to cover the first window and enlarge with an animation.
